# Nested Loops in Arm Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

Im working on project to translate the following C code to ARM assembly.

```
int i = 1;
int j = 0;
int x = 0;

int main(){
        for( ; i < 10; i += 2){
                for( j = i; j < 10; j++){
                x += i + j;
                }
        }
        return x;
}
```

I'm still having a little trouble understanding nested loops. This is what I have so far:

```
                                                                                                              
// DATA Section
.DATA
.balign 4
i:
        .word 1
.balign 4
j:
        .word 0
.balign 4
x:
        .word 0
.text
.balign 4

.global main
main:
        ldr r0, addressofI
        ldr r1, addressofJ
        ldr r2, addressofX
        b toptest
loop:
        ldr r4, [r0]            //load i to r4
        add r4, r4, r1          //add i + j
        add r4, r4, r2          //add x + (i+j)
        str r4, [r2]            //store new x in R2 address
        ldr r5, [r2]
        add r3, r2, #1          //add 1 to i
        str r1, [r0]            //store value of i in j
toptest:
        cmp r0, #10             //compare i to 10
        blt bottomtest          //jump to bottomtest if pass
        ldr r3, [r0]            //load i to r3
        add r3, r3, #2          //i+2
        str r3, [r0]            //store i+2 in r0
bottomtest:
        ldr r4, [r0]            //load i to r4 (equal to j)
        cmp r4, #10             //compare i to 10
        blt toptest             //less than = loop
branch:
        ldr r4, [r0]
        add r4, r4, #2
        str r4, [r0]
        b toptest
end:
        mov r0, r2
        bx lr

addressofI: .word i
addressofJ: .word j
addressofX: .word x
```

Not getting the right output, seems like its terminating early. If anyone can point out the issue I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Just up front, your life (and code) will be a lot simpler and more efficient if you keep `i,j,x` in registers throughout, rather than loading and storing them again every time.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping with a debugger?  That will almost certainly show you exactly what is wrong.  Trying to guess from the output is an exercise in futility.

Comment: Anyway, nested loops are not really anything special.  Just block out the outer loop as you would any other, and where its body should go, write the inner loop.

Comment: `add r4, r4, r2`   adds `i+j` to the address of `x`, not to `x` itself.  You'd have to load `x`, add the value to it, and then store it back.  Which is another reason why keeping everything in registers will make life much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I figured out the issue by setting j=i at the end of the bottom loop.